# Does Restore "From database" restore from the most recent backup of the database or the actual live database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

In SSMS 2005, I want to use the GUI to copy a database by restoring in to a new database.  I was using the "From database" radio button for the source, but then the databases in the list disappeared recently.  I read the sql server documentation and it says that only databases that are on record as having a backup  will show up in this list.  Nothing in the documentation says whether this backup will the actual data source or not.

When I select "From Database" in the source options, does it pull from the most recent backup of the database, or the actual live database?

Comment: I would also encourage you to become familiar with the `RESTORE DATABASE` commands. Relying on the UI can be problematic and your steps through the UI can be difficult to remember never mind add to source control.

Answer (score 3):

It will not pull from the live database. There is no SQL command for this (yet). It will give you a selection of recent backups you can pick from. You can only restore from a database snapshot and from a backup, not from a live database.

Answer (score 1):

At least in 2008, the Restore GUI is populated from the backup history tables in `msdb`. I assume in 2005 it works the same way. (Note: even if your servers are still 2005, it's worth it to upgrade your management tools.)

When you use the "Restore from database" list, you'll get a restore from the last backup you took of that database on that server (which may or may not be what you want).